# Hibernate could not execute JDBC batch update

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc, entitymanager

I have an error: javax.persistence.PersistenceException:

org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update

I persist my object to database by entiyManager with the following code:

```
    public void addPrincipal(Principal u) {

        trns.start();
        trns.getManager().persist(u);
        trns.commit();

}
```

trns is an object of transaction class I wrote myself, here's the code for used methods:

```
 public void start() {
    EntityManager manager = managerFactory.createEntityManager();
    manager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.set(manager);
}

public void commit() {
    EntityManager manager = entityManager.get();
    if (manager == null || !manager.getTransaction().isActive()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No transaction is in progress");
    }
    manager.getTransaction().commit();
    manager.clear();
}

public EntityManager getManager() {
    EntityManager manager = entityManager.get();
    if (manager == null) {
        start();
        manager = entityManager.get();
    }
    if (!manager.getTransaction().isActive()) {
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
    }
    return entityManager.get();
}
```

The Principal mapping class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "principal")
public class Principal implements Serializable {

@Id

@Column(name = "id_principal")
private Long id_principal;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "surname")
private String surname;

@Column(name = "designation")
private String designation;

@Column(name = "address")
private String address;

@Column(name = "telephone")
private String telephone;

@Column(name = "fax")
private String fax;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "legal_form")
private String legal_form;

@Column(name = "krs")
private String krs;

@Column(name = "authority")
private String authority;

@Column(name = "pesel_regon")
private String pesel_regon;

@Column(name = "nip")
private String nip;

@Column(name = "stock")
private float stock;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "principal", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private RepresentationPerson representation_person;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "principal", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private ContactPerson contact_person;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "principal")
private Set<StudyCommisioned> study_commisioned;
```

Getting records from database is not a problem. The only error occurs when I want to save new record to the database

Here's full stack trace. Sorry, I've forgotten:

```
com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager$RpcInvocationException: Unable to invoke method click in com.vaadin.shared.ui.button.ButtonServerRpc
at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:172)
at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118)
at com.vaadin.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleBurst(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1678)
at com.vaadin.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleVariables(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1564)
at com.vaadin.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleUidlRequest(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:582)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:315)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:201)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:170)
... 26 more
Caused by: com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod$MethodException: Invocation of method buttonClick in pl.edu.utp.badania.ui.innercomponents.AddPrincipal$1 failed.
at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:528)
at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:167)
at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:984)
at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:367)
at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:56)
... 31 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:93)
at pl.edu.utp.badania.postgresql.PgSQLTransaction.commit(PgSQLTransaction.java:35)
at pl.edu.utp.badania.postgresql.dao.PrincipalDAO.addPrincipal(PrincipalDAO.java:28)
at pl.edu.utp.badania.ui.innercomponents.AddPrincipal$1.buttonClick(AddPrincipal.java:147)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
... 35 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1389)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1317)
at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:81)
... 43 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:76)
... 43 more

Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Zadanie wsadowe 0 insert into principal (address, authority, designation, email, fax, krs, legal_form, name, nip, pesel_regon, stock, surname, telephone, id_principal) values ('sdasd', 'dfsd', 'asdasd', 'ppp@ppp.com', '3211', '12456', 'Osoba fizyczna', 'dasdas', '4312', '3212', 11.0, 'asdasd', '1234', 2) zostało przerwane. Wywołaj getNextException by poznać przyczynę.
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2753)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1887)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:405)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeBatch(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2900)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
... 51 more
```

Comment: The full stack trace of the exception provides extremely useful information. read it, and post it.

Comment: It seems not to be the **full** stack trace

Comment: Well, it's all I got from Tomcat log.

Answer (score 1):

- Try to run the insert statement in the stack trace

  insert into principal (address, authority, designation, email, fax, krs, legal_form, name, nip, pesel_regon, stock, surname, telephone, id_principal) values ('sdasd', 'dfsd', 'asdasd', 'ppp@ppp.com', '3211', '12456', 'Osoba fizyczna', 'dasdas', '4312', '3212', 11.0, 'asdasd', '1234', 2)
- Check constraints in the table. There may be more constraint in table UNIQUE KEY , FOREIGN KEY constraints

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be caused by the absence of a @GeneratedValue annotation or an error in the code that manage the ids, if the absence of @GeneratedValue is intentional.

From the [ObjectDB](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id) documentation for JPA primary keys:

> If an entity has a primary key field that is not marked with @GeneratedValue, automatic primary key value is not generated and the application is responsible to set a primary key by initializing the primary key field.

Comment: But with @GeneratedValue was exactly the same

Comment: What was the mapping defined with @GeneratedValue? If @GeneratedValue was used without a GenerationType, it means that the JPA provider (Hibernate) will select the strategy to generate the primary key values according to the database. For PostgreSQL, it appear when I look at the docs that a sequence will be used. See the [Hibernate documentation for the mapping of the id](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id).